# Wrote over partition map, now unable to boot even after attempted repair

Tags: macos, partition

Long story short - I was attempting to install bootcamp on my MBP and I suppose I wrote to a partition on my main ssd instead of the secondary ssd as intended. I attempted to create a new partition map with gpt following a couple guides on here, but that hasn't worked, yet. I have installed a temporary OS on my other ssd to try and salvage this little mess. I am running testdisk right now - looks like it's going to take at least until tomorrow morning to finish. I am also searching for a string with wxHexEditor to see if my recovery drive is in the right spot.

Here is what I get with `$ gpt -r -vv show /dev/disk1`:

```
gpt show: /dev/disk1: mediasize=240057409536; sectorsize=512; blocks=468862128
gpt show: /dev/disk1: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk1: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk1: Sec GPT at sector 468862127
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  467182904      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  467592544    1269544      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  468862088          7 
  468862095         32         Sec GPT table
  468862127          1         Sec GPT header
```

I am concerned that my bootable recovery drive isn't the correct size / in the right place as I don't necessarily know where my main parition (-i 2) ends and the recovery hd (-i 3) starts. Anyone have any tips / advice / pixie dust?

I should probably mention that this ssd that was overwritten was running Mac osx 10.9.5 and had 3 partitions.. the EFI, one main HFS+ partition called "Macintosh HD" and the bootable recovery tool.

EDIT-

So i was able to get the EFI and recovery drives located, recovery drive shows up on boot.. but strangely no Macintosh HD. I currently have:

```
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  467182912      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  467592552    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
```

a little messing around with the values led me here. I am not sure how the main partition doesn't fit exactly between the other two partitions. Still waiting for testdisk to finish.

UPDATE-

testdisk finished with... something?

```
Disk /dev/disk1 - 240 GB / 223 GiB - 468862128 sectors

The harddisk (240 GB / 223 GiB) seems too small! (< 458 GB / 426 GiB)
Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection...

The following partitions can't be recovered:
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
   MS Data                460956631  533228502   72271872
>  Mac HFS                467592548  895367499  427774952
```

and this

```
>P EFI System                    40     409639     409600 [EFI]
 D Mac HFS                   409640   39555455   39145816
 D MS Data                   673792   39817215   39143424
 D MS Data                 39817215   78960638   39143424
 D Mac HFS                 39817600  467592551  427774952
 D MS Data                264185819  264191992       6174
 D MS Data                264191992  264198165       6174 [Boot]
 D MS Data                285524923  285531096       6174
 D MS Data                285531096  285537269       6174
 D MS Data                285749728  285752607       2880 [EFISECTOR]
 D MS Data                286311211  286317384       6174
 D MS Data                286317384  286323557       6174
 D MS Data                286332483  286338656       6174
 D MS Data                286338656  286344829       6174
 D MS Data                314337648  314501487     163840
 D MS Data                333788472  333791351       2880 [EFISECTOR]
 D MS Data                333791352  333794231       2880 [EFISECTOR]
 D MS Data                346249935  395076302   48826368
 D Mac HFS                348200848  349526767    1325920
 D Mac HFS                376154434  376271089     116656
 D Mac HFS                381646688  381653539       6852
 D Mac HFS                382068096  382074947       6852
 D MS Data                386925054  387133917     208864
 D EFI System             387453152  387862751     409600 [EFI]
 D MS Data                388684760  460956631   72271872
 D MS Data                390287032  390289911       2880 [NO NAME]
 D MS Data                390290368  390293247       2880 [NO NAME]
 D MS Data                395076302  443902669   48826368
 D MS Data                464862801  465987152    1124352
 D MS Data                465127232  465128639       1408 [NO NAME]
 D MS Data                465987152  467111503    1124352
>P Mac HFS                467592552  468862087    1269536
```

The first and last parts look good, but I haven't a clue as to what is going on in the center. Can anyone decipher that?

Comment: Creating a new partition table typically wipes all record of **all** partitions on the disk -- probably not what you want. (Not the actual data, but the header that says where the partitions start and end.) Did you actually end up creating a new partition table, or does it show your original partitions? If you did overwrite the partition table, you've got a bit of a problem.

Comment: I have used `gpt destroy` and `gtp create` and `gtp add`, so i am sure the partions are obliterated. I searched through using wxHexEditor and found 2 instances of "HFSJ" exactly 2048 bytes apart, as someone suggested (I think it was @klanomath but I cant find the link) that that was the start of the recovery drive? Now I am searching again for "efiboot" string [as recommended here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175551/fix-formatted-gpt-in-ssd)

Comment: I added an update, I am more confused. Where did all of those Mac HFS parts come from?

Comment: I am still at a loss. Anyone have any advice?